# what is the difference between technical rule and function in ILOG JRules?

Tags: java, rule-engine, rule, ilog, jrules

Could anyone explain what is the actual difference between technical rule and function in ILOG JRULES ? . As far as i have seen, what ever we can achieve in function can also be achieved in technical rule. What's the exact difference ?

Regards,

Vinoth Kumar T

Answer (score 1):

That's like saying whatever can be achieved in Java can be achieved in assembly code. A technical rule will pattern match on a disparate set of Java objects simply by using the insert command on the objects. To achieve the same functionality using functions requires considerably more effort.